# Echo'ing a "{FORUM_NAME}" and Ignoring the "{}"

Tags: php, tags, phpbb

I'm looking for something that Is really hard for me to do.. I really tried to search all over the net for Solution, But I couldn't seem to find any. I also tried doing this for hours.

---

What I'm doing: Making a theme for PHPBB2, Installed a MOD that can include PHP in themes.
What is the problem: When I'm doing {} tags in php, It just can't echo those tags.
Let's say I have a function that creates a Table for me, like that:

```
CreateMyTable(Name,Size,Color);
```

I put in the function those strings:

```
CreateMyTable("{FORUM_NAME}",1000,red);
```

The title stays blank, I actually want it to echo {FORUM_NAME}.
How can I do this?

P.S: I can't do this

```
CreateMyTable(?>{FORUM_NAME}<?php , 1000, red);
```

It's not going to work becuase `<? = <!-- PHP --> , ?> = <!-- ENDPHP -->`.

- Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try using single quotes? Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Can't you just write `"FORUM_NAME"` or `FORUM_NAME` (if `FORUM_NAME` is a constant) or `'{FORUM_NAME}'` (if you really want to output `{FORUM_NAME}`)?

Comment: No, It will echo FORUM_NAME, and not the actuall forum name. If I do {FORUM_NAME} in html it echos the FORUM NAME.

Comment: It seems that the `{FORUM_NAME}` parsing is done by the template engine, so you can't simply do that perhaps (or there can be another way. Try any combinations till you're out of luck)?

Comment: Is FORUM_NAME a PHPBB2 format tag, or a PHP constant? If a constant, you would just use it in the function, without quotes. If some sort of PHPBB2 tag, then the fact you have it in a function is probably the problem, as it is maybe not getting parsed, because it is inside the PHP.

Comment: @fred2 - I'm pretty sure it's a PHPBB2 format tag, which would be replaced by the template parser.

Comment: @nickb My guess would be you need to find a solution whereby FORUM_NAME is not used inside your PHP.

Comment: Umm.. I tried '{FORUM_NAME}' before I asked those questions. Nothing helps.. I tried too many functions.. to many things.. and I can't seem to find the fix for this. And it's in the template, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the PHPbb2 template class, you'll find that the template is simply an evaluated set of PHP using the eval() function.  You can either print the contents of the PHP before it is parsed using eval() and then use the variable name that the template gives, IE something like (which may not work depending how your template is setup):

```
CreateMyTable(((isset($this->_tpldata['.'][0]['FORUM_NAME'])) ? $this->_tpldata['.'][0]['FORUM_NAME'] : '' ),1000,randomcolor());
```

Please note, in order to do it similar to the way above you'd actually have to insert this into your template class.

An much better solution is to avoid using the mod that allows PHP in templates and use JavaScript in the templates to create the function, then print a call to that JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
CreateMyTable(FORUM_NAME,1000,red);
```

I also noticed that `red` is used without quotes - is this also a constant? If it's a variable it needs to have a `$` in front of it. If it's a string it should be between quotes.

```
CreateMyTable(FORUM_NAME,1000,"red");
```

Comment: I think `{FORUM_NAME}` is supposed to be a variable that a parser interprets, not the actual table name or a constant. If so, than that's pretty nasty - creating tables with view syntax... TBH I have no clue what's going on here.

Comment: @WesleyMurch good point. @user1557994 if this is supposed to be a variable, GET RID OF THE ALL-CAPS NAME, change it to $forumName or $forum_name (whichever naming convention you use is up to you) and try `CreateMyTable($forum_name, 1000, $red);`

Comment: It's not a variable either. It's a tag used by PHPBB parser, and therefore can't be used within PHP code.

Comment: Yes it is. I just gave an Example. The real function is:
CreateTable("{FORUM_NAME}",1000, randomcolor());